# Derivatives of the Riemannian Exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with its Levi-Civita connexion $\nabla$. Fix $x\in M$ and $v,w\in T_xM$ two given tangent vectors. For all $s,t\in [0,1]$, set $\Gamma(s,t)=\textsf{Exp}_x(t(v+sw))$ (assume that it is always well-defined). How can I compute $D_s\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s}(0,t)$, where $D_s$ is the covariant derivative along the curves $\Gamma(\cdot,t)$?

In other words, call $J_s$ the Jacobi field along the curves $\Gamma(s,\cdot)$, corresponding to the variations given by $\Gamma$. I want to know how $J_s(t)$ varies, for any fixed $t$, as a function of $s$, locally around $0$, and express it solely as a function of $v$ and $w$, probably using the curvature of $M$.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't a Hessian only well defined on a manifold at critical points of the map?

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. In the Riemannian context (more broadly, given an affine connexion), the Hessian of a function $f$ is $\nabla df$, which makes sense everywhere. It coincides with the Hessian defined only at critical points at these points (if the connexion is symmetric)

Comment: Sorry, the title is misleading, since it is not exactly a Hessian that I am looking for.

Comment: @TrivialPursuit I agree, you should modify the title a bit imo

Comment: Could you say more about what you want? You can express the answer as the solution to the Jacobi equation (ODE). Do you want details of this or you want something more?

Comment: If I was considering $D_t\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial s}$, then I could write the Jacobi equation, but this is not what I want. It would be enough if I could prove an upper bound on $\|D_s\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial s}(0,t)\|$, where the norm is given by the metric in $T_{\Gamma(0,t)}M$ - an upper bound that would depend on $v$, $w$ and $t$.

Comment: I am interested in this because this is a way of measuring how the curves $\Gamma(\cdot,t)$, for any fixed $t>0$, differ from being geodesic curves in nonzero curvature.